# Keep HTML-link within a list in the same line as ::before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have replaced the common disc of a list with a FontAwesome symbol using the ::before pseudo-element. Everything works fine so far:

### CSS-Code (Example 1)

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\f007";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  margin-left: -3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li { 
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

li a {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

### HTML (Example 1)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net">JsFiddle</a></li>
</ul>
```

See: [Example 1 on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyge0hsr/1/)

But now, I'd like to display the links in the list as block element. Usually, this is done by addiing `display: block;`in `li a`. So the CSS-Code in Example 1 changes to:

### CSS-Code (Example 1*)

```
li a {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

However, the links do not remain in the same line any more, see: [Example 1* on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyge0hsr/2/)

What is missing/What is wrong? When using `display: block` in combination with the default list style (without pseudo-element), everything works as expected (that is: the link is displayed as block element; the link and the disc symbol of the list are still in the same line):

### CSS-Code (Example 2 - the standard)

```
ul {
  /* default: list-style: disc; */
}

li { 
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

See: [Example 2 (Standard list with link in block-style)](https://jsfiddle.net/91qw35en/)

Comment: `display: block` makes the element take the whole width. That's why it's breaking to a new line. Why exactly do you need to use that property?

Comment: Actually, I don't need ```display: block```. It's just because I don't want to force the user to exactly hit a link in the list. Just clicking the line is more comfortable. Using ```display: block``` within common lists does the trick. But it doesn't work with psudo-elements. The answer below solves my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these two property/values to `li a` selector:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

- `display: inline` is the default for `<a>`. Width cannot be set -- inline elements are formless like water.
- `display: block` makes elements solid and occupies the whole area right and left by default. Even if its width is set to something smaller, it will insist that it'd be the only one to occupy its own line. That's the reason for the displacement seen in [Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/cyge0hsr/2/). Block elements are unyielding like metal.
- `display: inline-block` will sit easily with neighbors to the left and right of it and width can be set. Inline-block elements are flexible like clay.

BTW for aesthetics try `text-decoration: none` on `li a` and don't forget:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

in that specific order.

---

#### Demo

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Verdana
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

li::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.45;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "\f007";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  padding: 0.15rem 0 0 0;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.45;
  height: 21px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: solid 1px red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net">JsFiddle</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://example.com" title='XXXXXXXxxxxx XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXX  x  xxxXXXXX XXXXXXxxx XXX XXXXxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXx xxxxxxxx'>XXXXXXXxxxxx XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXX  x  xxxXXXXX XXXXXXxxx XXX XXXXxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXx xxxxxxxx </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I've already tried ```display: inline-block```, but without ```width: 100%```. This does the trick.

Comment: Excellent, happy coding!

Comment: Ah, there is a small pitfall: If the link consists of several words and if the link is displayed in two lines (for examle due to a small screen), the icon is displayed at the baseline of the second line (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/8L0cnso6/). Actually, the icon should still be displayed at the basline of the first line. ```vertical-align: top``` is a workaround, but a rather ugly one. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Instead of worrying about unsightly bloated links, keep them as one line. If you really need to have more than one line of text -- use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` so that the text is truncated with `...`. Then give the link a title attribute with the full text so when the user hovers over the link, the whole text is revealed. See updated answer.